# how to get some substring in sql separate of ":" with the simplest query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, substring, charindex

this is my variable

```
 declare @fecha varchar(50)
 set @fecha='29:14:2'
 select 
horas= CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING (@fecha,1,
 charindex(':',@fecha)-1))
```

**@fecha could to have this format

```
set @fecha='9:4:2' or set @fecha='29:59:59'
```

i need get hour=24, minutes=14, second=2 with the simplest select

as you see i could get the hour only, but other two are confused :s

I know i need to get again the index where is first : until other : and so i could get minute but his was confused for me and i got only errors converting "4:",":",":1"

Comment: Please clarify: is 29 really a valid hour? Does the incoming string end as a duration in hours?

Comment: yes this is because I'll use datediff(hour,29,'1900-01-01')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
declare @time varchar(32) = '29:14:2'

select hh = convert(int,
              left( @time ,
                charindex(':',@time)
                - 1
              )
            ) ,
       mm = convert(int,
              left(            right(@time,len(@time)-charindex(':',@time))   ,
                charindex(':', right(@time,len(@time)-charindex(':',@time)) )
                - 1
              )
            ) ,
       ss = convert(int ,
              right(               right(@time,len(@time)-charindex(':',@time) )   ,
                len(               right(@time,len(@time)-charindex(':',@time) ) )
                - charindex( ':' , right(@time,len(@time)-charindex(':',@time) ) )
              )
            )
```

And it will almost certainly break if — **when** — your data isn't clean.

Answer (score 0):

[`charindex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) allows to give a starting position from where to search

> Syntax
>
> CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )

So you can save the position of the first colon `:` and start one character later for the second colon

```
declare @fecha varchar(50) = '29:14:2'
declare @pos1 int = charindex(':', @fecha)
declare @pos2 int = charindex(':', @fecha, @pos1 + 1)
select horas = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@fecha,1, @pos1 - 1)),
       minutas = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@fecha, @pos1 + 1, @pos2 - @pos1 - 1))
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd6e0/17)

Comment: its there where its confused for me, i got problem for example  declare @fecha varchar(50)
 set @fecha='29:14:2'
 select 
horas= CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING (@fecha,1,
 charindex(':',@fecha)-1)),
 minutos=SUBSTRING (@fecha,
 len(SUBSTRING (@fecha,1,
 charindex(':',@fecha)-1)),
 charindex(':',
 (SUBSTRING (@fecha,1,
 charindex(':',@fecha)-1)
 )-1
 ))

Comment: maybe I am doing it more dificult than it is

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend selecting the indexes of the colons in variable first, then running your parsing of the string based on that. Here's the raw code I used in SSMS:

```
declare @fecha varchar(30)
set @fecha='9:4:2'
select
      cast(substring(@fecha, 1, HourLimiter - 1) as INT)
    , cast(substring(@fecha, HourLimiter + 1, MinuteLimiter - HourLimiter - 1) as INT)
    , cast(substring(@fecha, MinuteLimiter + 1, len(@fecha) - MinuteLimiter) as INT)
from (
    select
          charindex(':', @fecha) AS HourLimiter
        , charindex(':', @fecha, charindex(':', @fecha)+1) AS MinuteLimiter
    ) t
set @fecha='29:59:59'
select
      cast(substring(@fecha, 1, HourLimiter - 1) as INT)
    , cast(substring(@fecha, HourLimiter + 1, MinuteLimiter - HourLimiter - 1) as INT)
    , cast(substring(@fecha, MinuteLimiter + 1, len(@fecha) - MinuteLimiter) as INT)
from (
    select
          charindex(':', @fecha) AS HourLimiter
        , charindex(':', @fecha, charindex(':', @fecha)+1) AS MinuteLimiter
    ) t
```

I also have a table-based solution on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cffa/2).